# How can I change my wordpress description when search using google search engine

Tags: wordpress, elementor, datastax-astra

[enter image description here][1]

My website shows an incorrect description when searched on google. my site URL is

Please, how can I change it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest installing Yoast (https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/).

Once installed, head to your home page in the backend, and lower on the editing page is the Yoast settings. In here you can edit the description that shows in Google.

Answer (score 0):

If you using custom theme just edit the tag in head:

```
<meta name="description" content=here">
```

but for it to change when searched on Google, it usually takes 2 to 3 days